# Rails - Changing the URL title through Rails Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I asked this question on Code Review but they suggested I ask it here

I'm trying to create custom routes for every web page in my show action.

```
Movie.all.each do |movie|
  match "/#{movie.title.downcase}", to: 'movies#show', via: 'get', 
  as: :"#{movie.title.downcase.gsub(/[:.]/, '').gsub(' ', '_')}"
end
```

This code matches every web page to my not found page.

```
resources :movies, except: [:show]
```

It should match the web page to the actual page.

I only have a show.html.erb file in my views folder. Could that be the problem?

Is it possible to use string interpolation on view file names?

I can't use Rails REST routing because I need to have better URLS.

```
/Movie Title
```

is a better URL then

```
/movies/1
```

That is why I need to optimize this code. It works, but it could use improvement.

I have no idea how to fix this. Here are a couple things I thought of.

```
Using Rails route redirection to another action
Using wildcard as view names (*.html.erb)
```

Remember: My only goal is to change the URL name to the movie's title

Comment: Have a look at the `friendly_id` gem (https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). It does most of the things you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using FriendlyId gem

Here's the link:

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/README.md

Add it to your Gemfile

Then add following to your model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
```

Then run this on rails console:

```
Movie.find_each(&:save)
```

To save slugs for existing movies

The documentation is quite good, feel free to comment if you have any trouble.